# selecting a row out of a date range (opposite BETWEEN statement)

Tags: mysql

I think, i need the opposite of mysql's BETWEEN function.
I have a given date (example '2013-09-14') and a mysql-table filled with date ranges like:

```
date_from  | date_to    | someotherdata  
2013-08-07 | 2013-08-29 | ...  
2013-09-13 | 2013-09-16 | ...  
2013-09-21 | 2013-09-27 | ...
```

(this is given, i cannot change the structure)

I want to select all entrys, where my given date is between date_from and date_to, but this does not work with BETWEEN :(

Any good ideas?

Comment: Could you please update the question to show the `select` with `between` that did not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `between` like that:

```
select * from your_table
where '2013-01-25' between date_from and date_to
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/11bbc/2)

There is no need for a column name before the `between`. It can be a static date too.

Comment: Sorry. Wanted to edit my answer and accidentally edited yours.

Comment: @SaschaPresnac: if you want the date **not being** between the range (as your post title says) you might want to try `where not '2013-09-14' between date_from and date_to`.

Comment: man, i am blind, you're so right. i think, i was staring too long onto this. this answer is right! excuse the disturbance

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select * 
  from your_table
 where not '2013-09-14' between date_from and date_to;
```